# Using bootstrap in already existing ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I have recently created a regular WebSite project in ASP.NET. I've created lots of functionalities like logging in manually (regular TextBoxes, redirecting to other pages and so on). Now I am wondering whether it is possible to remake the project to use Bootstrap so my website would look better. Is there any easy solution to that? Can it be done so that I don't have to rewrite whole project from the beginning? The project at this moment has over 1000 lines so it would be great if I could set the bootstrap without rewriting everything.

The project is NOT MVC. It is a Web Forms.

Comment: I just have to clarify one thing: Bootstrap will only affect your UI part of the application. So you don't have to rewrite the whole project. For reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1930623.aspx?Converting+existing+WebPages+site+to+Twitter+bootstrap+how+

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do that, but if I were you, I would either change the website into MVC, or even make it ASP.NET Web API/AngularJS that would be much better for further development.

Comment: @SorrelVesper, do you have any more information or any tutorial on how to do it? The reference you have provided says only that it is possible, however I do not have any experience on Bootsrap so I don't understand everything that is said there.

Comment: @EhsanAbd Will I lose everything I have written so far? If it is possible to convert the project to MVC or any other project you mentioned, will I lose a lot of time to write the code from the beginning? Sorry, I do not know a lot about ASP yet.

Comment: If you already have a Web Forms app, Ehsan's comment would be difficult to implement without a lot of rewriting, unless you thought ahead and abstracted all your logic, which you probably didn't (On the other hand, 1,000 lines of code is barely any.). And yes, you can add Bootstrap to an existing Web Forms app, it's actually pretty simple. Just add the correct references as described on the Bootstrap website (ideally you'd add them to your master page) and then apply classes to your HTML elements as necessary.

Comment: ehsan88's answer confuses people.  Bootstrap in web forms and making it MVC are not related at all, I really dont see the point of bringing MVC into the conversation.